# spring batch read list of POJO and process

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to read a list of POJO , pass it to ItemProcessor ? I am using a DAO class to fetch the List of POJO. How to configure it in a ItemReader,so that it can be used by processor?
I tried to read the List using ItemReader implementation, but the resultset is being fetched continuously. But it needs to be read just once.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rewrite your question because is not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JdbcCursorItemReader.

You can refer [Example Here](http://websystique.com/springbatch/spring-batch-read-from-mysql-database-and-write-to-a-csv-file/)

Comment: I already have a DAO to pick the records and convert it to List of beans. I only need to use them in Processor. Any suggestions pls

Comment: @KCMS : Basically you need to use some ItemReader implementation from the SPring batch. As Chaitu mentioned, you can try to use JdbcCursorItemReader that will take care of passing list of POJO's to processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the list in `beforeStep` or `beforeJob` depending upon your use-case and use the same list in the `read()` method of `ItemReader`as shown below,

```
public Object read() {
    if(!processDataList.isEmpty()){
        return processDataList.remove(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

After successful write, try to mark the status of read records so that it cannot be reprocessed.

Please note, it is recommended to use `JdbcCursorItemReader` or `JdbcPagingItemReader`. As you are saving all the records in the list, in case if the volume of records is more then it may cause memory issues.